# glitch on my meshes (Except wireframe mode)

Tags: 3d-view

[image: Can not get rid of this regardless of updating B2.8]

Any help ? Might be my video card?

Comment: Might also be the fact, that Blender 2.80 is still in Beta.

Comment: https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449/what-is-the-problem-with-posting-an-image-or-link-and-asking-how-do-i-do-this

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos I am not understanding what I did wrong.

Comment: Your questions should explain thoroughly through words what the issue is and what you did to achieve it, not just post an image ask "*Any help?*" and hope others will invest the time to blindly guess what is wrong. You should also be aware that Blender 2.8 beta is nowhere near ready, so issues are totally expected.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos I apologise if I offended you. I am new in the forum. Your description seems a little bit cynical. The reason why I did not "thoroughly" explained was just cause I thought it was "self-explanatory". It is on the title and the picture its quite graphical. Again, next time I will do it better. But I think we need to find a balance between how I asked help and how do you perceive it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the usual problem where you set extreme ranges in the Clip Start/End values. Try to keep the Start Value to be at least a 1/10000 of the End value.

[image]

Comment: I loaded factory settings and now it looks right again. I suspect is cause the clip start was also modified and now is the default one. Thanks!